# LoadXml hanging C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to convert an XML to JSON with JSON.NET. The problem for me right now seems to be that the code hangs during LoadXml.

```
                XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
                Console.WriteLine("1");
                xDoc.LoadXml("discordBotFiles/xmldata.xml");

                Console.WriteLine("2");
                String jsonConversion = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xDoc);

                Console.WriteLine("3");
                JObject textToJson = JObject.Parse(jsonConversion);
```

It doesn't matter what the XML is, no matter the content in the XML, it always hangs at the LoadXml call. The print to console was to determine where it was hanging.

Edit: I have changed LoadXml to Load but it still doesn't throw an exception and still hangs.

Edit2: Sigh, I found the exception. I didn't show up in console, but it showed up in Output in Visual Basic. I didn't think to look there.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Xml.dll

Comment: Are you sure it hangs, and not that it throws an exception? You're using the wrong method to load your xml *file*, as the parameter to `LoadXml` is the actual XML, not the filename, as such I would assume that the code is actually throwing an exception. Are you running this in a thread?

Comment: How large is the xml file?  Using XmlDocument on huge files is slow and you should use an XmlReader to read the file in smaller pieces.

Comment: I have changed it to Load, but it still hangs, sigh. And the file is VERY small. Sadly I fear posting here since I'm making a nsfw app.

I'm not sure if it's running it in a thread, been only coding C# for a month doing small programs. This was my first big one. It's running under async though.

Comment: Have you verified whether it does or does not throw an exception?

Comment: How do you know it doesnt throw an exception?

Comment: Can you show the rest of the method?

Comment: Aha, nvm, it does throw an exception. Just not in console but in output in Visual Basic.

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Xml.dll

Answer (score 0):

`XmlDocument.LoadXml` takes the xml contents as an argument, not the file name. If you want to read a file, use `XmlDocument.Load`.

And I'm pretty sure it doesn't hang - it throws an `XmlException`, since the data being parsed (`discordBotFiles/xmldata.xml`) is not valid Xml. If your application hangs, it's in your exception handling, not `XmlDocument`.